# pip3 install scrapy doesn't work and return a error code 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, pip

Python 3 is not my default version. I want to use it, because one the package I want to use `toripchanger` is only avaible under Python3.

So my `pip3` version is:

```
C:\Users\Truc>pip3 -V
pip 19.0.2 from c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

When I run the command

```
C:\Users\Truc>pip3 install scrapy
... #a lot of lines
#then
Command "c:\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='C:\\Users\\Truc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hw8khaqe\\Twisted\\setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',open(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n','\n');
f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install 
--record C:\Users\Truc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-msw6xh4l\install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed 
--compile" 
failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Truc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hw8khaqe\Twisted\
```

I already tried this

```
pip3 install setuptools
```

and this

```
pip3 install wheel
```

because I saw that in another topic, but it does not work and I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the requirements for building the twisted wheel.
I know for sure compiling anything for python on windows requires the [Visual C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/), and installing those might be enough to get your pip command to work.

Another solution would be to download a pre-built one from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted and install it. (`pip3 install file_you_downloaded.whl`)
Once twisted is installed, try installing scrapy again.

Comment: After run this `C:\Python\Python37>pip3 install Twisted-18.9.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` --> `Installing collected packages: Twisted
Successfully; installed Twisted-18.9.0`, the installation of scrapy worked well `C:\Python\Python37>pip3 install scrapy` --> `Installing collected packages: scrapy; Successfully installed scrapy-1.6.0`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for your case the best choice is to install [Anaconda or Miniconda](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#platform-specific-installation-notes) tools.

Answer (score -1):

Try updating:

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: I did two things, the exact command you wrote `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and even `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`, so for the last command I obtain: `Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages (40.8.0)`, but I still get the same error: `failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Truc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hw8khaqe\Twisted\ `  What I can add is during the process of `pip3 install scrapy` it prints `Failed building wheel for Twisted, Running setup.py clean for Twisted`