# ImportError: No module named toripchanger, how to launch scrapy with right python version

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror, tor

Python 3 is not my default version. I want to use it, because one the package I want to use `toripchanger` is only avaible under Python3.

So my `pip3` version is:

```
C:\Users\Truc>pip3 -V
pip 18.1 from c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

I use a scrapy.spider that I used to run in python 2.7 version and it works perfectly, but know I am using 3.7 in oder to use `toripchanger` I precised in my files this at the top of it:

```
#!"C:\Python37\python.exe"
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

the code above concerns the spider's file itself, the `middlewares.py`, the `settings.py`, the `items.py`, and `pipelines.py`.

In the `middlewares.py` I added some lines:

```
...
from scrapy.conf import settings
from toripchanger import TorIpChanger
...
ip_changer = TorIpChanger(reuse_threshold=3)

class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    _requests_count = 0

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self._requests_count += 1
        if self._requests_count > 10:
            self._requests_count = 0 
            ip_changer.get_new_ip()

        request.meta['proxy'] = settings.get('HTTP_PROXY')
        spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])
```

The issue when I run my spider `scrapy crawl spider` is I obtain this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Truc\...\middlewares.py", line 13, 
in <module> from toripchanger import TorIpChanger
ImportError: No module named toripchanger
```

*You may see the whole lines of error at the end of this topic*

The issue for me is I tried what it is provided in that [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources) so I did `pip3 install setuptools` even `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`, I did `pip3 install Twisted-18.9.0-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl` as adviced in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736716/pip3-install-scrapy-doesnt-work-and-return-a-error-code-1) because it was necessary to install `scrapy` in my python 3.7 version.

*As I said, the whole lines of error, where I see `c:\python27` while I precised `#!"C:\Python37\python.exe"` in my files*

```
[in] scrapy crawl spider
[out]

2019-02-18 14:27:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot:I_AM_A_POLITE_ROBOT)

2019-02-18 14:27:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, 
cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, 
w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.9.0, 
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)], 
pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017), 
cryptography 2.1.4, Platform Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
2019-02-18 14:27:11 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings
{'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'folder.spiders', 
'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['folder.spiders'],
'RETRY_TIMES': 5, 'BOT_NAME': 'I_AM_A_POLITE_ROBOT',
'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [401, 403, 404, 408, 500, 502, 503, 504],
'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2}

2019-02-18 14:27:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
'scrapy.extensions.throttle.AutoThrottle']

2019-02-18 14:27:11 [py.warnings] WARNING: 
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\deprecate.py:
156:ScrapyDeprecationWarning: 
`scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware` 
class is deprecated, use
`scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware`
instead ScrapyDeprecationWarning)
Unhandled error in Deferred:

2019-02-18 14:27:11 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

2019-02-18 14:27:11 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1386, in
_inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 98, in crawl
six.reraise(*exc_info)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
self.engine = self._create_engine()
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 69, in __init__self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line88, in __init__self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
mwcls = load_object(clspath)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 44, in load_object
mod = import_module(module)
File "c:\python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module__import__(name)
File "C:\Users\...\middlewares.py", line 13, in <module>
from toripchanger import TorIpChanger
ImportError: No module named toripchanger
```

Comment: how are you calling `scrapy`?

Comment: as aws_apprentice is hinting, if you do "python myfile" and your myfile has the hashbang of "#!"C:\Python37\python.exe"", your system will still use the default python (probably 2.7 for your system).  The hashbang only works if the file is run directly from from a shell.. usually in *Nix systems like "./myfile.py".  Windows probably ignores the #! notation.

Comment: You need to include the actual command you use to start the program.

Comment: Also windows will use the "%PATH%" variables to find executables for files (i.e. which path to find the python.exe to run *.py files.) and not the hashbang.  You will need to change to path items to remove the C:/Python27 references or you will have to do it like this "C:\Python37\python.exe scapy.py".. also isn't the Windows exe file called wpython or pythonw or something??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just in case you installed Python 2.7 after 3.7, Windows will by default consider the latest installed Python version as the default version.

Comment: No. My versions 3.7 is the lastest installed and it do not makes it the default version automatically, at least in my windows 7 version.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will always use the default python.

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable

To use some other python version without changing the Windows default, you must do something like this (the exact path will vary per system setup):

```
C:\Program Files\[your python path]\python.exe "myfile.py"
```

Comment: The issue is this solution means to make a script, and it is not the case of my spider. I use arguments in the command to makes differents versions of the spider like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977185/how-to-run-several-versions-of-one-single-spider-at-one-time-with-scrapy). Besides to be honest, when I downloaded another version of python I managed to crawl it with the version 3, but it asked for a module win32 that couldn't be installed by pip because it was not available anymore it was a mess of issues.

Comment: So I tried what abccd suggest in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074371/how-do-i-use-scrapy-in-different-versions-of-python) like this `py -m scrapy crawl spider -a arg1=machin -a arg2=bidule` it worked in the python 3 version I installed, and as I told you just 10 minutes ago I obtain `import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'` and when I try to install it with `pip3 install win32api` I obtain `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32api (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for win32api`

Comment: You need to change your question.  You can either 1) change the default python version, -or- 2) launch the proper version of python some other way. (or provide more information on why you can't start your program; your comments are unclear).

Comment: At the present, your question indicates your issue is an import error; which is not the case:  You are not running the correct python and your question is amounting to an endless back and forth on possible problems.